# How can I check if any element from a certain column of one array is in the text within a certain column of another array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, list, if-statement

First: I have a vector of data - a column of one dataframe (let's call it vector A).
Second: I also have second dataframe with a column, containing similar data (vector B).
Third: I need to check if any element from the vector A is inside the strings (elements) of the vector B.

For example: vector `A = c("A10", "A25", "A87")`
The vector `B = c("strain A8", "strain A25", "strain A35")`
Result: FALSE, TRUE, FALSE

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to do a substring match with `grepl`

```
grepl(paste(A, collapse="|"), B)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or if it should be an elementwise comparison, `str_detect` (Vectorised over string and pattern) can be used

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(B, A)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
A <-  c("A10", "A25", "A87") 
B <- c("strain A8", "strain A25", "strain A35")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you help.

Comment: But, the first method gives me all TRUE results

Comment: The second method return this error: Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: @Saltcress - that's not true. Both suggested chunks of code clearly work for the example data you presented and which akrun used. If you have a different structure in your actual data, then you need to present that in your question.

Comment: @Saltcress I have showed the data used in my post.  If it is a factor class, convert it to character with `as.character(B)` or `as.character(A)`

Answer (score 0):

The above works if a bool result will suffice. If you need the actual matched element you could use `stringr`'s `str_subset` method like this:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(B, A)
```

Which returns:

```
"strain A25"
```